# What is the pure Korean version of 동생?

Tags: hanja

I wonder why some words have or do not have pure Korean version. One explanation I found is that everyday basic usage words have Korean version because they originated long time ago. The more modern a word is, less is the likelyhood of a Korean version.

So, what is the pure Korean version of 동생?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several terms, all of which are archaic in the standard. There was a fluidity with the terms, just as 동생 is used across both genders nowadays.

- a younger brother, but also younger sibling in general: [아우 in standard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%95%84%EC%9A%B0#Korean), most commonly seen in [translations of the Bible](https://www.bskorea.or.kr/bible/korbibReadpage.php?version=COGNEW&book=gen&chap=4&sec=1&cVersion=&fontSize=15px&fontWeight=normal) into Korean; 아스 in Hamgyeong; 아시 in Jeju; all are from Middle Korean 아ᅀᆞ [*azo*; note the archaic hangeul there]. Although Wiktionary currently says 아우 refers to a man's younger brother, I don't see much of a difference in usage; there is some suggestion that it was originally [a younger sibling of the same gender](http://eurogenes.blogspot.com/2016/02/chg-admixture-in-early-western.html).
- a sister, of either a man or a woman: [누이](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/f9c301dccf2949c995e76be617d153b4) in standard, from Middle Korean 누의, although this could refer to an older sister as well as a younger sister originally, it [ended up being distinguished by custom](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/f9c301dccf2949c995e76be617d153b4) from 누나 and 언니 to mean "younger sister".